# IIS 6 not returning my custom http headers

Tags: http-headers, iis-6

Running IIS 6, I want my website to have

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"
```

in the header of the response.  I did add it in my web site properties > HTTP Headers and add it there.  I've recycle the AppPool, restarted IIS but still the header doesn't appear in the response.

I've been able to achieve that with IIS 7 by adding it to the httpProtocol>customHeaders section of web.config but I've read it doesn't work with IIS 6.

What did I miss?

Comment: Same issue occurs with development server that comes packaged with Visual Studio. IIS express is a nightmare for me to debug with Wcf Service